# JavaScript function(callback).then(), callback executes after then

Tags: javascript, callback

I have trouble to get this to work.

I have a function `getItem`:

```
export const getItem = async (key, callback) => {
    value = await Expo.SecureStore.getItemAsync(key).catch((error) => console.log(error));
    callback(value);
}
```

`getItem` is supposd to get a token and pass that token to the callback.

Now I want to use `getItem` in this (simplified) class:

```
export class Post {
    constructor(){
        this.token = false;
    }

    post() {
        console.log('Token: ' + this.token);
        ...
    }

    setToken(token){
        console.log('Set token.');
        this.token = token;
    }

    authorizedPost() {
        getItem('token', this.setToken.bind(this)).then(
            this.post()
        );
    }
}
```

I use this class like this:

```
let post = new Post();
post.authorizedPost();
```

This is the output I get:

```
Token: false
Set token.
```

But I need the token to be set and after that, I want to call the method `this.post()`;

Since I'm a beginner, I want to excuse if that issue is trivial. But I am thankful for every help!

Comment: You need to pass a function to `then` not the result of a function: `then(() => this.post())`. ps. mixing callbacks and promises is a recipe for confusing code.

Comment: `.then(this.post());` does not do what you intended. Try `.then(() => this.post());`

Comment: Thanks, and thanks for the tip with promises and callbacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you didn't really ask, but…

Part of the reason the code is difficult to debug is because you are using callbacks when you don't need to and mixing them with promises. These are two different async paradigms that are normally better off separate. You can get rid of the callback in your code in a way that will make it *much* more readable.

```
 Expo.SecureStore.getItemAsync()
```

returns a promise, so just return it.

```
const getItem = (key) => Expo.SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);
```

Then in your method you can call `then` and simply call the function you were passing as a callback. No need for callback or bind. Just one line after the other:

```
authorizedPost() {
  getItem('token').then(val => {
    this.setToken(val)           // the order is now obvious
    this.post()
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
}
```

Here's a snippet with a faked `Expo` method:

```js
let Expo = {
  SecureStore: {
    getItemAsync() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve("someFancyToken"), 1000))
    }
  }
}

class Post {
  constructor() {
    this.token = false;
  }
  post() {
    console.log('Token: ' + this.token);
  }
  setToken(token) {
    console.log('Set token.');
    this.token = token;
  }
  authorizedPost() {
    getItem('token').then(val => {
        this.setToken(val)
        this.post()
      })
      .catch((error) => console.log(error))
  }
}

const getItem = (key) => Expo.SecureStore.getItemAsync(key);

let post = new Post();
post.authorizedPost();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that example!

Answer (score 2):

I had to pass a function to then like this:

```
authorizedPost() {
        getItem('token', this.setToken.bind(this)).then(
            ()=>this.post()
        );
    }
```